# Sumar líneas de columnas dependiendo del valor de una tercera

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla, `lineas`, con cinco campos:

```
id
subcuentad_id
subcuentah_id
imported
importeh
```

Otra tabla, `subcuentas`, con dos campos:

```
id
denominacion
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es lo siguiente:

Por cada subcuenta, coger su `id` y sumar en la tabla `lineas` todos los registros de las columnas `imported` e `importeh` cuyas `subcuentad_id` o `subcuentah_id` sean iguales al `ID`.

De manera que si `id`, por ejemplo, número `8` aparece en la tabla `lineas` 100 veces en `subcuentad_id` y su suma total es `100.00`, y aparece 200 veces en `subcuentah_id` y su suma total es `200.00`, obtener el sumatorio.

> ID=8 imported=100.00 importeh=200.00

Teniendo en cuenta que estos valores pueden ser mucho más grandes y, en vez de `100` o `200` veces, pueden ser `2000` o `4000`.

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Podrías explicar de forma sencilla qué es lo que quieres sumar y bajo qué condiciones? No se entiende nada, es un trabalengua lo que has expuesto. A veces el principal problema es **no saber explicar el problema**. Explícalo en una sola oración, por ejemplo: *«Quiero que si se cumple esta condición, se sume tal cosa basándose en tal columna y si se cumple esta otra condición se sume tal cosa basándose en tal columna»*

Comment: Ejemplo. una subcuenta tiene un ID determinado por ejemplo el 15 en la tabla 'subcuentas' ,cuando ese 15 esté en la columna subcuentad__id   de la tabla 'subcuentas' quiero que sume el importe de la columna imported y cuando ese 15 esté en la columna subcuentah_id de la tabla 'subcuentas'quiero que sume el importe de la columna importeh de la tabla 'subcuentas'

Comment: Estoy redactando una respuesta, pero me llevará tiempo porque estoy haciendo un db-fiddle con datos de ejemplo (si hubieras compartido el esquema de la tabla mi respuesta sería más rápida).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer el trabajo puedes hacer una subconsulta que calcule la suma para cada `id` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
  subcuentas.id,
  subcuentas.denominacion,
  (
    SELECT SUM(imported) FROM linea
    WHERE subcuentas.id = linea.subcuentad_id
  ) imported,
  (
    SELECT SUM(importeh) FROM linea
    WHERE subcuentas.id = linea.subcuentah_id
  ) importeh
FROM subcuentas
```

La consulta va recorriendo cada uno de los registros de `subcuentas` y mostrando el `id`, la denominación y calculando la suma de los campos `imported` en los que el campo `subcuentad_id` sea el que coincida con `id` y la suma de `importeh` en los que coincida con `subcuentah_id`.

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/422g1FTkq2HkQ1V1wJM5wM/0).